# yii, search for a value from textfield in database

Tags: php, html, database, search, yii

```
I have this code on my view,

<div class="text-id-box">
<?php echo CHtml::textField($model,'id'); ?>
</div>

<div class="submit-box">
<?php echo CHtml::button('Search', array(
'submit' => array('SiteController/actionSearch',
array('id'=>$id)))); ?>
</div>
```

and my database:
id: varchar(8)
name: varchar(20)
location: varchar(50)

i wanna search id in my database, then return name, and location value. how to build its model and controller.
any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: do scaffolding in yii  , it automatically create search function along with grid.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. first generate the model using gii  ref (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii)
> 2. then you can add following function in your controller

```
public function actionSearch($id)
{
 $model= new Yourmodel;
 $model=Yourmodel::model()->findByPk($id);
  //you will get the row for particular id
 // and you can access it by $model->name $model->location
 // render the required page and access to model object to get the name and location.

}
```